# ¿Cómo traducir "current events" al español?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

En la escuela tuvimos una clase que llamábamos "current events".

Me preguntaba ¿cuál sería el nombre de aquella clase en una escuela latina?

He pensado en "eventos de actualidad" y "eventos actuales".

Estoy buscando una traducción, especialmente la que se usaría para el nombre o descripción de una clase sobre eventos que están pasando en el mundo ahora.

Comment: Se acostumbra a decir también *hechos contingentes.*

Comment: @Ustanak : No sería traducción adecuada. "contingente", en castellano, tiene relación con "eventual". Pero no con "event".

Comment: @leonbloy Lo decía por *current.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que bastaría con decir simplemente *Actualidad*.

Answer (score 6):

Soy profesor y en ocasiones utilizamos *Acontecer Nacional e Internacional* lo que vendría siendo *"Cosas que suceden nacional e internacionalmente"*

Comment: +1 por `acontecer nacional e internacional`.

Comment: @Mauricio gracias por el comentario, ha sido un placer haber podido ayudar

Answer (score 2):

He aquí algunas sugerencias:

- Sucesos actuales.
- Acontecimientos actuales.

Habría que ver cuál era el contenido de esa clase o curso.

De ser de naturaleza periodística, quizá la primera forma fuera preferible. Si la clase tuviera un enfoque histórico o sociológico, preferiría la opción *"Acontecimientos actuales"*.

Answer (score 1):

"Acontecimientos actuales". Suena correcto y natural en España.

Answer (score -2):

I would use "Cosas que suceden internacionalmente" if you're talking about international events.

Comment: Why *internacionalmente* stands for *current events*?